# How do I fix error "I do not know the key '/tikz/show background rectangle'"

Tags: tkz-euclide, tkz-fct

I don't know why, but I keep getting issues using the tkz-euclide package. Here are several problems:

**Problem 1**:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\usetkzobj{all}


\begin{document}
\tikzset{background rectangle/.style={fill=black}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle]
\tkzInit[ymin=-1.5,ymax=7,xmin=-1,xmax=+11]
\tkzClip
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
\tkzDefPoint(1,0){I}
\tkzDefPoint(10,0){A}
\tkzDefPointWith[orthogonal](I,A) \tkzGetPoint{H}
\tkzDefMidPoint(O,A) \tkzGetPoint{M}
\tkzInterLC(I,H)(M,A)\tkzGetPoints{C}{B}
\tkzDrawSegments[color=white,line width=1pt](I,H O,A)
\tkzDrawPoints[color=white](O,I,A,B,M)
\tkzMarkRightAngle[color=white,line width=1pt](A,I,B)
\tkzDrawArc[color=white,line width=1pt,style=dashed](M,A)(O)
\tkzLabelSegment[white,right=1ex,pos=.5](I,B){$\sqrt{a}$}
\tkzLabelSegment[white,below=1ex,pos=.5](O,I){$1$}
\tkzLabelSegment[pos=.6,white,below=1ex](I,A){$a$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/show background rectangle
' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.11 ...in{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle]

? 

Process has been terminated ...
```

What it's supposed to look like:

[image]

I also have one more question:

How do I install tkz-fct(for drawing graphs and functions), how to use it, and which articles I can use?

Comment: If you use MikTeX, there is a package manager to install new packages.

Comment: In order to use `show background rectangle`, you need to say `\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}`.

Comment: I took the liberty of making the title more descriptive, hope you don't mind.

Comment: Thank you for making the title more descriptive! It does actually make it easier to understand!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once I add `\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}`, there is no error.

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{background rectangle/.style={fill=black}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle]
\tkzInit[ymin=-1.5,ymax=7,xmin=-1,xmax=+11]
\tkzClip
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
\tkzDefPoint(1,0){I}
\tkzDefPoint(10,0){A}
\tkzDefPointWith[orthogonal](I,A) \tkzGetPoint{H}
\tkzDefMidPoint(O,A) \tkzGetPoint{M}
\tkzInterLC(I,H)(M,A)\tkzGetPoints{C}{B}
\tkzDrawSegments[color=white,line width=1pt](I,H O,A)
\tkzDrawPoints[color=white](O,I,A,B,M)
\tkzMarkRightAngle[color=white,line width=1pt](A,I,B)
\tkzDrawArc[color=white,line width=1pt,style=dashed](M,A)(O)
\tkzLabelSegment[white,right=1ex,pos=.5](I,B){$\sqrt{a}$}
\tkzLabelSegment[white,below=1ex,pos=.5](O,I){$1$}
\tkzLabelSegment[pos=.6,white,below=1ex](I,A){$a$}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the `\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}`!